# Pip installation of .whl file only generates *.dist-info folder

Tags: python-3.x, pip, raspberry-pi3, python-wheel

I have an application that I am trying to build and install as system-wide executable. The odd thing is that the build is fine, but when I call:

> python3.5 -m pip install --upgrade some-name.whl

All is successful, the executable is system-wide accessible, but cannot import the module where the entrypoint is.

This is the setup.py:

```
setup(
    name='ppldetect',
    version=version(),
    packages=find_packages(exclude=['docs', 'tests', 'tests.*', '*.tests', '*.tests.*']),
    author='',
    author_email='',
    description='',
    setup_requires=['sphinx', 'nose', 'wheel'],
    install_requires=['Pillow', 'AWSIoTPythonSDK'],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'ppldetect = publisher.basicPubSub:main',
        ]
    }
)
```

This is the error I get when I try to execute the command:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ppldetect", line 7, in <module>
    from publisher.basicPubSub import main
 ImportError: No module named 'publisher'
```

I've upgraded pip to the latest version. Interesting enough, I have been using the very same **setup.py** as template for quite some time now and never had issues before.

All the other projects I've used it on are building and working fine.

**NOTE**: I am trying to run this on Raspberry PI, all other projects I've tried under Ubuntu.

**EDIT**: I build the .whl like this:

> python3.5 setup.py bdist_wheel

Comment: Please, create [mcve].

Comment: I will add an answer, it was just a typo as it looks. Maybe we can vote on closing the question as well.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortuantely, IDEs are making us lazy and not quite observant.

As I am doing all this in Raspberry with limited resources, I had created an `__init__` file maunally and had totally forgotten to add the .py extension (as PyCharm does it itself) and once added all went fine.